# weird series sorting problem in Highcharts bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Full code example here:** https://jsfiddle.net/_dario/o6nugkrw/24/

I have a data series structured like this (from an API call):

```
 {
    "mango": 12736,
    "orange": 8906,
    "banana": 8404,
    "2020": 8239,
    "blackberry": 7703,
    "pear": 7297,
    "raspberry": 6895,
    "apple": 6432,
    "kiwi": 6202,
    "tomato": 6189,
    "1995": 6123,
    "kumquat": 6038,
    "melon": 5982,
    "strawberry": 5973,
    "pineapple": 5441
  }
```

The sorting order is value high to low, regardless of the label. These are to be plotted in an Highcharts horizontal bar chart.
*Notice there are two numeric (string, though) labels: "1995" and "2020"*.

This specific data format is then parsed for Highcharts:

```
//--previous highcharts options
series: Object.keys(data).map((s, index) => {
      let arr = new Array(length).fill(null, 0, length);
      arr[index] = data[s];
      return {
        name: s,
        data: arr,
        tooltip: {
          headerFormat: ''
        },
      }
    }),
//--subsequent highcharts options
```

as per the jsfiddle example (https://jsfiddle.net/_dario/o6nugkrw/24/), the sorting order along the Y axis in the chart is different, and no matter what the order the data is presented in, the two "numeric" labels always stay on top and are sorted differently (by numeric value).

I found no reference in the Highcharts docs about this and would like to have them treated as "words" like the others and sorted accordingly. I believe the error might be in the parsing above, but cannot find it.

Comment: you need a different structure than an object, because per specification are index like values sorted to top in order.

Comment: Your problem is not related to using the Highcharts library, take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r02bxhwp/